# Opacity fade in and out text SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to fade in and out a timer in SwiftUI.  When the timer starts, I would like it to fade in.  When the timer reaches "00:00", I would like the timer to fade out.

Here is my code so far.  It will fade-in, but it won't fade-out.  endTransition turns to true when the countDownTimerTransition reaches "00:00"

```
VStack (alignment: .leading) {
     Text("TIME REMAINING")
          .font(
          .system(size: 13)
          .uppercaseSmallCaps()
     )
     .foregroundColor(Color(.lightGray))

     Text(whichButtonWasPressed.countDownTimerTransition)
          .font(
          .system(size: 13)
          .uppercaseSmallCaps()
          )
          .foregroundColor(Color(.lightGray))
}
.position(x: globalCenterX, y: globalCenterY)
.transition(.opacity.animation(endTransition ? .easeIn : .easeOut))
```

Comment: I think there is a part that control this entire VStack appear/disappear right? can you show it? because I don't see the part where this entire VStack would appear when a condition is met.